# MySql, join tables WHERE IN()

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have two tables and structure here:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `membership` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `memberships` (
  `id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `memberships` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1,  'Basic'),
(2,  'Bronze'),
(3,  'Gold'),
(4,  'Platinum');

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `membership`) VALUES
(1,  'john', '0'),
(2,  'mike', '1,2'),
(3,  'peter', '3,4'),
(4,  'jane', '3'),
(5,  'rick', '1,2,3');
```

I need to join both tables and list all users with their memberships using IN function.

This is what I tried, but I'm not able to join tables that way:

```
SELECT 
  *.u
  m.title AS title 
FROM
  `users` AS u 
  LEFT JOIN `memberships` AS m 
    WHERE m.id IN(u.membership)
ORDER BY u.username;
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
username              membership
=====================================
john                  null
mike                  Basic, Bronze
peter                 Gold, Platinum
jane                  Gold
rick                  Basic, Bronze, Gold
```

I have created SQL fiddle as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39b6e1

Comment: `SELECT u.*` not `*.u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
  u.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(m.title SEPARATOR ', ') as memberships
FROM
  `users` AS u 
  LEFT JOIN `memberships` AS m 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(m.id, u.membership)
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY u.username
```

Gives you:

```
id  username    membership  memberships
4   jane        3           Gold
1   john        0           (null)
2   mike        1,2         Bronze, Basic
3   peter       3,4         Gold, Platinum
5   rick        1,2,3       Basic, Bronze, Gold
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39b6e1/8)

Comment: Isn't that a complicated way to do what `FIND_IN_SET()` does?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I wasn't aware of `FIND_IN_SET()`. Updated the answer to use that.

Comment: @Miro Markaravanes thank you works perfect. I have accepted your answer.